# How do I identify ongoing magical effects on a creature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Pretty much as the title says, if I go up against an uberbuffed evil cleric, how can I identify what buffs he has?

Detect magic only gives away the school of the spells, but I want to know if he has specific spells, and the details of those spells if possible.

I have no way of seeing him when he's buffing himself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### At low levels, identifying spells already in place probably can be done with a combination the spell [*detect magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic) and the skill [Knowledge (arcana)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge)

As you're already aware, a caster of the spell [*detect magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic) can, on the third round of study, attempt to detect the schools of any active spells within the *detect magic*'s effect.

Simultaneously, while able to view such auras so distinctly, a caster can attempt to "[i]dentify a spell effect that is in place" with a successful [Knowledge (arcana)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/knowledge) skill check (DC 20 + spell level).

At least, that's what I assume.

*Pathfinder*'s antecedent *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* uses the skill [Spellcraft](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/spellcraft.htm) to do this, but that skill's description for this skill use says

> Identify a spell that’s already in place and in effect. You must be able to see or detect the effects of the spell. No action required. No retry.

*Pathfinder* moved this skill use to the skill Knowledge (arcana) and shortened the description even more to where this skill use says only

> Identify a spell effect that is in place.

The *Retry: No* entry of the Knowledge skill answers one question, but others remain. Thus the GM determines how to identify a spell in place in *Pathfinder*. I assume many GMs (like me) port over how this works in *3.5* to *Pathfinder* with little distress. (In my campaigns a creature can't identify a spell in place without first identifying its aura; yours may vary.)

Under these rules, the spell [*detect magic*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic) allows an knowledgeable caster to take 3 rounds to attempt to identify spells in place, the spell [*arcane sight*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-sight) allows a knowledgeable caster to take a free action to attempt to identify spells in place, and the spell [*greater arcane sight*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-sight) allows even an ignorant caster to just *know* what spells are in place.

Identifying a spell *as it's being cast* remains a use of the skill [Spellcraft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/spellcraft).

Answer (score 4):

**You want [Greater Arcane Sight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-sight).**

Greater Arcane Sight is a 7th level sorceror/wizard and witch spell that lets you "automatically know which spells or magical effects are active upon any individual or object you see".

Comment: Anything available earlier?
Edit
Didn't see that it was 3rd lvl spell for a lesser version, that helps a lot thanks!
Edit to edit, I know see that it actually is the greater version that is what I'm looking for, guess I'm all out of luck!

Comment: @BabyGiraffe The lesser version does not let you know the effects that are active on the target; it's more like a faster detect magic with no need to concentrate on things, so you would presumably see the spells' auras and know their school, but not necessarily their exact effects.